# Replace fragment in host activity from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, callback

I have container activity that has framelayout for storing fragment inside it.
For example I have activity with initial framgent for login page. Theare are two buttons Login And Register.
User can click register and in this case I need to change my current fragment with another fragment with registration fields.
So I have only idea to make an host activity implement callback interface and than pass activity to fragment, and when user clicks register callback method is called and host activity replacing fragment.
So the question is if there is any other better way to do this, maybe more correclty.
Please leave your suggestions and how do you deal with this problem.Thanks

Comment: explain "with registration fields." ??? is it Registration Fragment ?

Comment: Yes it is another framgent with registration fileds, Registration Fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace fragments as follows ,

```
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(<container id>, new RegisterFragment());
    transaction.commit();
```

//if you are using support library, make sure to use getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: Is it better than make acitivty to be responsible for replacing fragments ?

Comment: it is the convenient way to add/replace fragments http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html also accept the answer if it helped you

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea, fragments are about modularity and if you give such responsibility to a fragment you will need to refactorize your code if you need to replace that fragment with something else in the future

Comment: So call back in this case is better ?

Comment: I think so, at least that's the way that I do it.

Comment: that was the easy and convenient way, but if you consider about future changes you may go with FragmentPagerAdapter http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html